Resizing windows using PyWinAuto
I am trying to resize a window (with robotframework), using PyWinAuto, though I am getting an error message:
KEYWORD screen_resolution . Set Resolution ${window}, 1800, 800
Start / End / Elapsed:  20240530 16:36:00.075 / 20240530 16:36:00.127 / 00:00:00.052
16:36:00.075    FAIL    ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected WinFunctionType instance instead of WinFunctionType

The code that I am having for the py file is:
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image
import pygetwindow as gw

def change_resolution(window_title, width, height):
    width = int(width)
    height = int(height)
    """
    Change the resolution of the specified window to the given dimensions.

    Arguments:

    window_title: The title of the window.
    width: The new width of the window.
    height: The new height of the window.    """
    window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(window_title)
    if window:
        window = window[0]
        window.resizeTo(width, height)
        window.moveTo((window.width - width) // 2, (window.height - height) // 2)
        print("xxx" + window_title)
    else:
        print("The window with the specified title was not found." + window_title)

# Define the keyword through which we change the screen resolution to the desired specifications
def set_resolution(window_title, width, height):
    change_resolution(window_title, width, height)**your text**

I have tried importing other libraries, though that didn't help.
Also, it is worth mentioning that this code is running inside a VM on mac (M2 processor)

I have removed
Library    RPA.JavaAccessBridge
import and afterwards the things are looking fine and I can ran the tests.
